# 1 month pregnant and offered a postdoc: when to disclose pregnancy?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, health

I work in bioinformatics (almost no lab work) in Europe. I have been offered a Postdoc position in California and just found out that I am pregnant. What should I do? Should I disclose my pregnancy this early considering that I don't even have a second heartbeat yet and miss the once-in-a-lifetime opportunity? Or go ahead with the job? will it give me problems during delivery and in the foreseeable future?

Comment: A quick search turns up (among other things):https://work.chron.com/disclose-employer-pregnant-3494.html

Comment: You should be aware that government-mandated support for those who have recently given birth is quite minimal in the US relative to most places in Europe. Not sure about California and with a temporary post doc job vs permanent position, but unless you learn otherwise you should expect that there is no paid time off. Your insurance may cover parts of care while pregnant and delivery, but you should plan for at least $5000-$10000 in additional out of pocket expenses even after your insurance pays for part.

Comment: You should read your employment contract and university policies, then consider your personal preferences.

Comment: @BryanKrause A postdoc in the USA with zero paid time off would be highly irregular, but probably legal.  Paid time off probably will not be enough to give birth unless you can afford to have someone else take care of the child.

Comment: You should have received health insurance information with your job offer.  Read it very carefully.  It could say *almost anything*.  It is certain to be confusing.

Comment: Also check housing costs.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Zero time off would be unusual but so would paid maternity leave. Something like 3 weeks paid vacation is....not similar to European family leave. I guess my comment was not clear that I was talking about benefits related to pregnancy and childbirth specifically. I doubt anyone can afford infant child care on a post doc salary.

Comment: You should consider moving this question to Law stackexchange. You have gotten some useful comments here. There is virtually no maternal leave in the US unless your employer grants it. Medical expenses might not be provided at all or there might be quite reasonable provisions in California, if only charity care. You might also need legal advice from an American immigration lawyer in California. Ask your prospective employer for a referral to an immigration lawyer.

Comment: Hi, I am going to recommend you ask this question in a group more suited to getting advice and experiences of women in academia. The Facebook groups “Tenure-Track Moms” or “Academic Mamas” would have lots on this.

Comment: I think your main concern should be trying to determine if you would be ok with an American maternity leave. Don’t worry about effects on the employer of your leave- work can be managed. Note that normal jobs in California have 12 weeks maternity leave. You should look at the web site of the university where you have the offer or ask for a referral to the HR department (tell the PI you want to “get clarity on taxes and benefits for international students”) to understand the specific policy for post docs.

Comment: In addition to all the other comments here: moving to a new country can be hard, and it takes time to build friendships and develop a support network. You should probably think carefully about the realities of caring for a newborn, and whether your circumstances would give you sufficient support if and when you need it.

Comment: @BryanKrause Hospital costs for labor & delivery really depend on the insurance (and hospital etc).  With my university insurance (not CA but in the US), at ~10 years ago I think we had to pay a total of about $500 for a birth with no complications.  For a more accurate estimate, the OP should find out what the insurance plan(s) is(are) and inquire with the insurance company.

Comment: @Kimball Agreed that OP will have to look into it beyond what general advice anyone here can offer.. I'm mostly concerned that someone not familiar with US healthcare may not realize what the range of scenarios includes here as it may be quite different from where they live now. Costs can also change a lot in 10 years, and an uncomplicated birth is only the best case scenario.

Comment: Another note on maternity leave in the US. I’m not sure about California, but the US Family Medical Leave Act (FMLA) only covers employees who have worked for their employer full time for at least a year. These employees are able to get (reduced) paid leave for at least 12 weeks after having a baby. Unfortunately this wouldn’t apply to the OP, and is the only help I’m aware of that can come from the federal government. California and the university may have other systems in place to help though. You are not however required by law to disclose your pregnancy.

Comment: The 1 year vesting point is really important.  For example, [at my university](https://hr.iu.edu/relations/parental-leave.html): "Paid parental leave is available to all staff employees at IU who are in non-temporary positions of 30 hours or more per week and have been continuously employed in a benefits-eligible position for at least 12 months before the date of the birth or adoption of a child."

Comment: @NoahSnyder The 1 year point may not be particularly relevant for post docs if they are considered "temporary employees" which I'm pretty confident I was as a post doc; in that case, from the passage you quote the benefit never vests even after a year.

Comment: I was confused because I was looking at the staff policy not the [academic appointee policy](https://policies.iu.edu/policies/aca-47-leaves-for-academic-appointees/index.html). You’re right that postdocs are excluded.  They can only take unpaid leave.

Comment: There is also a citizenship question.  Country of birth matters a great deal for the citizenship of your child.  In Europe it varies, but if they're born on US soil, they're a US citizen, full stop.  What that means for you is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you really need some advice on this, let me jump in. The comments are all worth considering but don't answer the question.

Yes, in the US, medical care is good, but financing for it is poor. Very poor compared with some parts of Europe. University employment normally comes with medical insurance that is "fine" by US standards, but maybe not by European standards. The numbers are shocking for unexpected medical expenses. Unrelated to reality, in some sense.

Parental leave is poorly supported here, though California is one of the better parts of the US for such things.

I don't think (but don't know) that there is anything in the law that requires you to disclose a pregnancy, but nothing that forbids it either. I doubt (but don't know) that an offer could be withdrawn if you reveal a pregnancy. I certainly hope we are beyond that, and California is one of the better places for such safeguards.

Let me suggest that you at least consider talking this over with the PI and get their advice on what is best and what your options are. In particular, it might be an option to delay the postdoc for a year. You might also be able to get, from the right PI, assurance that they will do "whatever it takes" to make it work out. Not everyone will be as accommodating, so there is some risk, but you need information as much as anything and they might be a good source of it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend checking what the local law says about informing an employer about the pregnancy. Second, it is a good idea to check with the HR of the university what benefits you are allowed to receive while on the specific postdoc contract. When you have all this information, you can think about the options which would fit your family best: either take the job or maybe it just would not be possible to financially support this.

In general, my advice is to think about yourself, first of all. Explore, plan and decide. If you decide that you can make and accept the offer, don't worry about disclosing this information asap. It's your private matter. You can inform your PI either when the law requires or earlier if you feel it like that.

Good luck!